# creating triggers on schema rather than all table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am using PostgreSQL. I have a schema 'cmp' under-which I have several tables e.g. customers,employees and etc. Every table has 'created' and 'modified' field (column). I want to update modified field with the help of trigger whenever there is any record update. I am choosing trigger for this operation but I have below issue:

I have to write trigger for each & every table individually. Is there any way I can write a trigger on a schema or a global schema which will update modified field of a particular table which caused trigger event?

Comment: You might want to check this out... sounds like you should use a column default value instead of a trigger:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910763/how-to-set-a-postgresql-default-value-datestamp-like-yyyymm

Comment: I have 'created' field set as timestamp not null default current_timestamp and 'modified' as timestamp default null so want to change from null to timestamp on update

Comment: It's true that you need to write the `create trigger` for each table, but all tables can use the same trigger *function* - so you only need to write the `create function` **once** (and you can easily generate the `create trigger` through a SQL statement - you can even write a function that creates all the triggers automatically)

Comment: Yes,  did the same thing. Written only one function which is being used by all the triggers in different table. Once and for all, had to write . Thanks guys for your inputs!